# setting "ignore privates" "ignore internals" has no effect for internal classes and their subelements

Tags: stylecop

For some strange reason StyleCop does not respect my documentation rule settings. Consider the following code:

```
internal class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
    }

    public SomeMethod()
    {
    }

    public SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And the following settings:

```
<Analyzer AnalyzerId="Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules">
...
    <AnalyzerSettings>
       <BooleanProperty Name="IgnorePrivates">True</BooleanProperty>
       <BooleanProperty Name="IgnoreInternals">True</BooleanProperty>
    </AnalyzerSettings>
</Analyzer>
...
```

I get the following messages form stylecop 4.4

- SA1600: The class must have a
  documentation header.
- SA1600: The constructor must have a
  documentation header.
- SA1600: The method must have a
  documentation header.
- SA1600: The property must have a
  documentation header.

Is this a bug or a feature? Shouldn't internal classes be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Stylecop from within Visual Studio, check if your settings are also ticked under StyleCop Settings -> Documentation Rules, might otherwise overwrite your settings at runtime.